# Laravel 5.1 multiple images move() issue

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have the following controller code, it should move all the five images to `uploads` directory but it moves only one image.

Controller:

```
if(Input::hasFile('profile_pic')){
    $pic = Input::file('profile_pic');
    $mobile->photo1 = $pic[0]->getClientOriginalName();
    $mobile->photo2 = $pic[1]->getClientOriginalName();
    $mobile->photo3 = $pic[2]->getClientOriginalName();
    $mobile->photo4 = $pic[3]->getClientOriginalName();
    $mobile->photo5 = $pic[4]->getClientOriginalName();

     foreach ($pic as $file){
       if(!empty($file)){
         $file->move(public_path() . '/uploads/', time() . '-' . 'laptop');

       }
    }
```

}

The images name are storing in database table fields successfully. But the  not all images are moving to the destination folder only one image moves to the folder, Check `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because for all the five images the filename would be same as this executes so fast that the time() returns a same value. So the image gets overwritten. You can append some unique string, maybe something like

```
    foreach ($pic as $k=>$file){
       if(!empty($file)){
         $file->move(public_path() . '/uploads/', time() . '-' . $k . '-laptop');

       }
    }
```

Yes, the code looks fine to me, but instead of getting the name of the file five times you can do it in a loop

```
$pic = Input::file('profile_pic');
foreach ($pic as $k => $file){
   if(!empty($file)){
     $mobile->{"photo".$k+1} = $pic[$k]->getClientOriginalName();
     $file->move(public_path() . '/uploads/', time() . '-' . $k. '-laptop');

   }
}
```

This way you wont be storing the file names if the file doesn't exist as well.

Comment: Yes it looks quite good to me, but read the suggestion above :)

Comment: Bro the above code is not uploading even a single image ! 
Error is  :
`The file "13-512.png" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.`

Comment: oh I forgot the `$k` in the file name

Comment: I have edited the post, try that. But you get the concept here right, looping and getting the orginalfilenames. there might be few bugs, try fixing them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out and you'll see the problem:

```
for ($i = 0; $i<=5; $i++) {
    echo time() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Since all of this is happening very fast, the value returned by `time()` which you use for a filename is always the same for every iteration.
Try generating a pseudo-unique filename, for example like so:

```
foreach ($pic as $file){
   if(!empty($file)){
     $file->move(public_path() . '/uploads/', md5(mt_rand(0,time())) . '-' . 'laptop');
   }
}
```